# Django | Redirect on First Login

Tags: python, django

I have to assume I'm going about this the wrong way... But I'm just learning Django, so I'd like some help.

I have a basic blog app.  I'd like a user to be taken to the feed regularly after login, but I'd like the user to be taken to their profile on the very first login.

Right now, this is in my settings.py:

```
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = 'Home'
LOGIN_URL = 'login'
```

So, the user is always taken to the feed, 'Home'.

I've tried importing the User model to settings and attempted something like this:

```
if not User.last_login:
    LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = 'Profile'
else:
    LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = 'Home'
LOGIN_URL = 'login'
```

but as soon as I've imported the User model to the settings.py file, the server will no longer run.  I guess that's something I can't do.

What's the best approach to achieve the desired outcome?

Comment: What's the error message?

Comment: The server crashes and the terminal tells me `raise ImproperlyConfigured("The SECRET_KEY setting must not be empty.") django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: The SECRET_KEY setting must not be empty.`  But then as soon as I remove `from django.contrib.auth.models import User` from settings.py, it works just fine again.